# How to get freb.xsl file in IIS_FailureTrace directory

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

I am running IIS on Windows Server 2012 R2. I follow the follow steps to enable 'failed request tracing' in IIS:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kishorerajendran/archive/2015/05/08/iis-failed-request-tracing.aspx

I get a `fr000001.xml file in my 'DataDir\Logs\IIS_FailureTrac` directory, but there is no freb.xsl file.  I tried go to IE and do `http://localhost`, that does not help.

How can I get the freb.xsl file?

Comment: Was that file never generated or you deleted it accidently?

Comment: it is never generated.

Comment: You can try deleting "IIS_FailureTrac" folder and recreating it with same name or different name. That may help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows Server 2008 R2, I completely deleted the `W3SVC1` folder in `C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\` .Then I requested again the page with my error. The folder `W3SVC1` was recreated, and this time it contained my failed request .xml as well as `freb.xsl`. (if that doesn't work, you could be lucky, try from a dos prompt, from `c:\`, `dir freb.xsl /s`. I've got multiple copies of it for iis, iisexpress, multiple web sites, etc... it's in `My Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles` for example)

Comment: Still a problem on Server 2012R2 at least. Fix still works: just deleted the lowest folder (W3SVCnnnnn,,,,,) and repeated failed request as stated, and it worked for me.